# Track device's uniqueness if factory reset is done?

Tags: profiles

Android device ID is changed with factory reset. Android 10+ no longer allows to track IMEI and serial number. Are there any other identifiers that can be used to detect if somebody used the same device twice using different e-mail?

Comment: Apps are not allowed to track. Did you read anywhere that Google doesn't? Curious

Comment: I know, but it doesn't mean they don't even if they are not allowed. So I want to make sure if there is still any way they are able to track if factory reset is done.